# JxBrower7.7 start timeOut error，Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

Tags: linux, arm, redhat, jxbrowser

linux：
[root@localhost bin]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

[root@localhost bin]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.0-115.5.1.el7a.06.aarch64 (mockbuild@arm-buildhost1) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (NeoKylin 4.8.5-36) (GCC)) #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 10:34:55 CST 2019

[root@localhost bin]# file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=8a346ec01d611062313a5a4ed2b0201ecc9d9fa1, stripped

JxBrower7.7：
i used this demo,the line 55 is:Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();

```
enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
    EngineOptions.newBuilder(OFF_SCREEN).build());
    Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();
enter code here
```

[root@localhost bin]# java -jar test.jar 
Exception in thread "main" com.teamdev.jxbrowser.navigation.TimeoutException: Failed to execute task withing 45 seconds.
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.navigation.internal.NavigationImpl.loadAndWait(NavigationImpl.java:248)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.navigation.internal.NavigationImpl.loadUrlAndWait(NavigationImpl.java:105)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.navigation.internal.NavigationImpl.loadUrlAndWait(NavigationImpl.java:82)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.navigation.internal.NavigationImpl.loadUrlAndWait(NavigationImpl.java:74)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.internal.EngineImpl.newBrowser(EngineImpl.java:458)
    at com.pinnet.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:55)

linux logs at /var/logs/messages:

22 09:48:53 localhost dbus[8661]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
May 22 09:48:54 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90562 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - dumping core
May 22 09:48:54 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90566 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (repeated crash)
May 22 09:48:54 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90561 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (repeated crash)
May 22 09:48:54 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90593 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (repeated crash)
May 22 09:48:55 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90624 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (repeated crash)
May 22 09:48:55 localhost abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 90623 (chromium) of user 0 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (repeated crash)
May 22 09:48:56 localhost abrt-server: Duplicate: core backtrace
May 22 09:48:56 localhost abrt-server: DUP_OF_DIR: /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2020-05-21-16:55:06-33694
May 22 09:48:56 localhost abrt-server: Deleting problem directory ccpp-2020-05-22-09:48:54-90562 (dup of ccpp-2020-05-21-16:55:06-33694)
May 22 09:48:56 localhost abrt-server: /bin/sh: reporter-mailx: 未找到命令
May 22 09:49:18 localhost dbus[8661]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out

Comment: I am also getting same error on Ubuntu19. Are you able to solve this issue